# Where does the instruction of an executable go to?

Tags: operating-system, system-calls, cpu-architecture

Please do not mark as Duplicate : I know that executable files such us .exe are a set of instructions in machine language (binary) but what I don't know if those instruction are targeted to the system (then to the kernel) and then to the CPU or they're read from the memory directly by the CPU ? I'm a bit confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arranging for executable files to run is done by the process loader, usually a part of, or executed by, the UI shell.

The exe file contains header metadata and executable code.

The loader reads the executable file header, allocates an initial working set of kernel and other resources that a process will need to run and creates a thread to run code at the process entry point.  If that code has not been read into memory by the loader, it will happen now in an immediate page pault loads it.

The process then exists, and a thread is running it.

Summary:  the image file, (.exe in Wondows), contains both metadata for interpretation by the OS loader AND executable code.  The executable code instructions are read into memory by the loader and the CPU fetches and executes those instructions from memory.

Comment: even though that I don't know what a loader is (I think it's a part of the OS) , and I don't know what a thread is , I can clearly see that the OS sets the table for the CPU to run the instruction by preparing the memory , am I right ?

Comment: @MekacherAnis essentially, yes:)

Answer (score 2):

Your question starts with a mistake.

> I know that executable files such us .exe are a set of instructions in machine language (binary)

Usually, an executable file is set of instructions how a program or library is to be loaded into memory. (There are some executables that are loaded as it into memory but those are normally used for operating system and embedded systems.)

A program or library will have data that is:

- Read Only
- Read Write
- Read Write initialized to zero
- Execute

A linker usually organizes the parts of a program in program sections that correspond to those groups.

The program load reads the instructions in the executable file and creates these sections. For read only data, the loader creates the appropriate pages, loads the data into them, and marks the pages a read write. Some systems actually map the memory page directly to the executable and uses the executable for paging those sections.

For a read write, initialized to zero section, the executable does not need to contain data. I just needs to tell the loader to create the pages and set everything to zero.

The executable will also define the dynamic libraries that need to be loaded and addresses fix ups (addresses that need to be fixed, depending upon where things are loaded).

If the executable defines a program (rather than a library) it will indicate the starting address of the program so that it can execute.

Comment: so you're basically saying that the executable contains information how its instructions needs to be laid out in memory , these information are platform specific (set by the linker) and the loader which is a part of the OS handles them , am I right please answer me ?

Comment: The linker will lay out the machine instructions in program sections within the executable. The executable tells how to load those program sections and fix them up if necessary.

Comment: so this why windows executable won't work on liunx machines  because the executable contains different type of instructions that windows loader  have to handle , am I right ?

Comment: Yes. Even when the the instructions will execute on a windoze and Linux machine, the executables are incompatible because of the executable format (and how they link to other libraries and system services).

Answer (score 2):

An executable has a bunch of metadata to tell the OS how to map it into memory, and what libraries it needs.  (The other answers cover this well).

So the OS sets up a fresh virtual address space for the process that ran `execve(2)` on this executable (or the Windows equivalent of that POSIX system call).  It maps the pages of the executable into that virtual address space, then jumps to the entry point (with a special jump instruction that drops kernel-mode privileges, like `iret` or `sysreturn` on [x86](/questions/tagged/x86)).

At this point, the CPU is now executing instructions directly from memory in the user-space process.  That memory is a copy of what's on disk.  (See [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache)).

No kernel code runs until the process makes a system call, or an interrupt arrives.  (e.g. the timer interrupt, at which point the kernel may decide that the process has had its share of CPU for now, and context-switch to a different process).

Comment: thank's for the explanation but I'm just a noob I don't understand most of the vocabulary and OS things as I'm just learning C++ , so what do u mean in a nutshell  , and thank's

Comment: @MekacherAnis: I mean the CPU runs instructions itself.  The kernel isn't involved on a per-instruction basis in feeding them to the CPU.

Comment: alright this is my recap tell what I get right and wrong : the executable contains instructions which tells the windows loader how it should be laid  out in memory , so at the end these instructions goes to the OS first so it prepares the environment for the CPU to do his  work , and windows is also responsible for freeing memory , and as a side note the instructions on how it should link other libraries and system services differs from an OS to an other . So am I right in what I mentioned ? thank's a lot

Comment: @MekacherAnis: sounds about right.  You should say "metadata", though, to avoid confusion with x86 machine instructions.

Comment: thank's man m even though I didn't study about OSs at least I know a little bit , thank's , really sorry for asking again , but can u explain in lay man words what is the difference between 64bit and 32bit  and thank's

Comment: @MekacherAnis: No, I can't, because there isn't just one difference.  You'd probably need more background knowledge to understand it in any meaningful way.

Comment: It's alright , thank's a lot . I'm just a hobbyist , I just wanna learn C++ for fun for my own entertainment  no commercial things , because we don't even study computer science at school , I don't think it's a necessity to keep learning , am I right  ?

Comment: @MekacherAnis: You can teach yourself about how computers work without studying it at school.  Search on SO and/or superuser.  And wikipedia

Comment: Actually, I've learned a lot from using Linux.  Since it's open source, info about how and why things are designed the way they are is out there in mailing list archives and even in the docs included in the source tree.  Google is pretty good at finding stuff.

Comment: well I agree with u about google , and I also think that stackoverflow is the best open community I've ever dreamed of , it's seriously up to u that I keep learning C++ , so thank's